# sql combining rows by ID, retain the information

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row

I am trying to find a way to combine different rows based off of an ID number.

Here is an example set of rows:

```
ID   |status     |Time
12345|  4        | 1:23
12345|  2        | 2:30
12345|  6        | 2:40
12345|  9        | 3:00
```

The Id's are the same for these so I would like to group them together someway but still have the individual times show for each status. What Im thinking it something like this:

```
ID   | Status 2 | Status 2 Time | Status 4  | Status 4 time | etc
12345| 2        | 2:30          | 4         | 1:23          | etc
```

Is this possible at all?  If there is another way to connect these ID's that would be easier that would be great as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I would guess... a pivot table?

Comment: It's not easy to do this, but your answer will be a dynamic pivot query. However, you didn't mention your overall goal for doing this. For example, time between status would go down a different path using row_number or lead.

Comment: @KeithL thank you for the reply! my overall goal is to use the times that the status changes for a report that will show orders that are still open.  so the orders that I want it to show will have a status time within a certain range depending on the predetermined cutoffs.  I will look into dynamic queries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this will pivot your data when the available statuses are only in the set 4,2,6, or 9.  If you don't know what values are in this column, you need to build and execute the pivot as dynamic sql.  There are examples of this in stack overflow.

```
-------------------------
--test data schema
DECLARE @tempdata as TABLE(ID int, [status] int, [time] time)
insert into @tempdata values

(12345, 4, '1:23'),
(12345, 2, '2:30'),
(12345, 6, '2:40'),
(12345, 9, '3:00'),
-- some extra data to show what happens with another id
(12346, 4, '6:23'),
(12346, 2, '7:30'),
(12346, 6, '7:40'),
(12346, 9, '8:00')

-------------------------
--The query
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM @tempdata) t
PIVOT
    (MIN([time])
    FOR [status] in ([4],[2],[6],[9])) as pvt
```